# Status orders - font color

Tags: hook-woocommerce

Please advise me - help.
How to change the font color for orders with status pending, pending payment and completed in the order list - my accounts| orders.
Thank you very much for your advice

I searched for the code here but couldn't find it.
I need to sort it out for more clarity in the order list.